# How to caculate the probability of this cell is mine

Tags: algorithm, probability

[the unknown one **blue** marked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQvEP.png)

it's 3/5? 1/3? 2/5? or max value of above, or maybe another(I think this...)?
how to caculate? it confuses me very much...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about maths/probability and not programming.

Comment: This might be considered more on topic at either https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/ or https://math.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually 1/2.

Note that there must be at least two mines in the three cells below 3 (because the other two cells are adjacent to a 1 and as such can't have more than 1 mine).

This means that there must be at least one mine between the cell below the 3 and cell to the bottom right of 3. Since both of these are also adjacent to a 1, only one of them can have mine at most. Thus, exactly one of these cells is a mine. The 2 on the right becomes irrelevant at this point.

With that out of the way, is there a general algorithm which can generate results like these?
I can't thing of any polynomial time solutions but it might be possible to simple try all the alternatives while backtracking when a constraint fails.

Comment: oh...I am sorry to not notice the 3 and 1, I think some of you options is right, but why the 2 on the right become irrelevant ? I don't understand...the 2 also influence  this cell is or not mine.